# How to get cell selection on touchdown?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom tablecell and trying to show a different icon when it's selected. The problem is icon changes only **after** **touchup** and not right after touchdown (unlike selection background image). Is there a way to change this behaviour?

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    let cell = self
    if (selected) {
         cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: (selectedIconName!))

    } else {
         cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: (iconName!))

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`setHighlighted`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/setHighlighted:animated:) instead of `setSelected` for that:

```
override func setHighlighted(highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super. setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)

    let cell = self
    if (highlighted) {
         cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: (selectedIconName!))

    } else {
         cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: (iconName!))

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Override `touchesBegan` in your custom cell subclass:

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell {
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
        // handle touch down
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off having a small model, `array[NSIndexpath]` then on `didSelectRow:` add the `indexPath` to the `array` and reconfigure the `cell`, passing in the selected state.

on `didSelectRow:`

```
if selectedPaths.contains(indexPath) {
    let i = selectedPaths.indexOf(indexPath)
    selectedPaths.removeAtIndex(i)
} else {
    selectedPaths.append(indexPath)
}

configCell(indexPath)
```

In your cellForRow: you can configure the cell with:

```
 cell.configure(selected: selectedPaths.contains(indexPath))
```